# How to add HTML 5 tags like (video & source) with mews/Purifier?

Tags: php, laravel-5, htmlpurifier

Im using  mews/purifier

Added video[style|controls|width|height],source[src] on HTML.Allowed in the config/Purifier but still it removes the video and source tag everytime I use clean() method.

Maybe It's because it's html 5 tag, but how can I allow those tags in Purifier?

Here is my default settings on config/Purifier

```
'default' => [
        'HTML.Doctype'             => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
        'HTML.Allowed'             => 'div,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src],video[style|controls|width|height],source[src]',
        'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
        'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => true,
        'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => true,
    ],
```

Comment: Seems like people are not too happy with that repo in general. Take a look here and follow the directions: https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier/issues/32#issuecomment-225628250